# How does the OpenSSL Alternative chains certificate forgery (CVE-2015-1793) attack work?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

The security advisory for the issue can be found here: https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20150709.txt

> ## OpenSSL Security Advisory [9 Jul 2015]
>
> ## Alternative chains certificate forgery (CVE-2015-1793)
>
> Severity: High
>
> During certificate verification, OpenSSL (starting from version 1.0.1n
>   and
>   1.0.2b) will attempt to find an alternative certificate chain if the first attempt to build such a chain fails. An error in the
>   implementation of this logic can mean that an attacker could cause
>   certain checks on untrusted certificates to be bypassed, such as the
>   CA flag, enabling them to use a valid leaf certificate to act as a CA
>   and "issue" an invalid certificate.
>
> This issue will impact any application that verifies certificates
>   including SSL/TLS/DTLS clients and SSL/TLS/DTLS servers using client
>   authentication.
>
> This issue affects OpenSSL versions 1.0.2c, 1.0.2b, 1.0.1n and 1.0.1o.
>
> OpenSSL 1.0.2b/1.0.2c users should upgrade to 1.0.2d OpenSSL
>   1.0.1n/1.0.1o users should upgrade to 1.0.1p
>
> This issue was reported to OpenSSL on 24th June 2015 by Adam
>   Langley/David Benjamin (Google/BoringSSL). The fix was developed by
>   the BoringSSL project.
>
> ## Note
>
> As per our previous announcements and our Release Strategy
>   (https://www.openssl.org/about/releasestrat.html), support for OpenSSL
>   versions
>   1.0.0 and 0.9.8 will cease on 31st December 2015. No security updates for these releases will be provided after that date. Users of these
>   releases are advised to upgrade.
>
> ## References
>
> URL for this Security Advisory:
>   https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20150709.txt
>
> Note: the online version of the advisory may be updated with
>   additional details over time.
>
> For details of OpenSSL severity classifications please see:
>   https://www.openssl.org/about/secpolicy.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the description, one may infer that the attack works the following way (warning: I wrote "infer" and I mean it -- I have not tried it):

- The attacker is in position to intercept all network traffic from the victim (e.g. the attacker operates the WiFi access point to which the victim unwisely connected).
- The attacker owns (legitimately !) some domain, let's call it "evilattacker.com", and has bought a completely valid certificate with that name in it; namely, the attacker owns a certificate *A*, that contains the name `www.evilattacker.com`, and is signed by some trusted root *V*. The attacker pushes a copy of that certificate (the public key) on a publicly accessible Web site, say his own site; the corresponding URL may be (for instance) `http://www.evilattacker.com/cert.crt` (it could also be on any kind of public hosting, it does not matter).
- The victim wants to connect to its bank site. His browser tries to open a SSL session with `www.bank.com`.
- The attacker intercepts that connection and pretends to be the bank. To that effect, the attacker sends a certificate chain *C*,*X* (in that order) where:

  - *C* is a synthetic certificate that contains the name `www.bank.com`, and is signed with the attacker's own private key, and contains an [`Authority Information Access` extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.2.1) with a URL equal to `http://www.evilattacker.com/cert.crt` (that is, pointing to where the attacker has published his own certificate *C*).
  - *X* is random junk.
- The client (victim's browser) will fail to validate the *C*,*X* chain, because *X* is random junk. If the browser uses an old OpenSSL, then things stop there and a connection error is reported. However, if the browser uses a new, affected version of OpenSSL, then it will try to rebuild an alternate chain, following the URL found in *C*. In particular, the browser will download *A* (the attacker's certificate) and then *V* (the external, trusted certificate authority), and will end up with the *C*,*A*,*V* chain.
- If there was no bug, then the client would reject that new *C*,*A*,*V* chain because even though all cryptographic signatures match, the middle certificate *A* lacks the [`Basic Constraints` extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9) with the `cA` flag set to `TRUE`: the attacker's certificate is not a CA certificate, so it cannot appear in the middle of a valid chain. However, due to the bug, in that specific situation, affected versions of OpenSSL fail to check the `cA` flag in the `Basic Constraints` extension, and accept that *C*,*A*,*V* chain as valid. The browser is persuaded that it talks to the genuine bank server, and proceeds without any warning. The attacker can now run a [Man-in-the-Middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and plunder the victim's bank account.

Ironically, failure to check the `Basic Constraints` extension for middle certificates was also a bug in Windows / Internet Explorer circa 2003, and Microsoft was duly and heavily mocked for that; the OpenSSL developers thus just lost all rights to such mocking.

The bug impacts every application that uses an affected version of OpenSSL (not a lot of them, since the buggy code was added only recently), and is in position to process a certificate chain sent by a potentially hostile peer. This means SSL *clients* (when validating a server's certificate); this also means SSL servers themselves, when (and only when) these servers request certificates from clients (certificate-based client authentication is pretty rare in everyday's Web).

Comment: OpenSSL has a new test case with some information for this bug: [test/verify_extra_test.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/593e9c638c58e1a510c519db0d024527113330f3#diff-34e5085afc62aa2dd21f6e952250f3bfR104). I don't get it.  I haven't checked the trust store but it seems weird that there would be a non self signed CA ("InterCA" in their example) in their trust store when it's signing CA is not also inside the trust store.

Comment: Nicer illustration here: https://twitter.com/maximilianhils/status/619153452086767616

Comment: OpenSSL dev [Matt Caswell tried to explain this on OpenSSL-users yesterday](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2015-July/001743.html). It appears that (1) no AIA downloading is involved, (2) the attacker does not need any MitM capability, just a regular HTTPS server (3) the attacker needs detailed knowledge what is in the victims trusted store and untrusted store in order to send a an untrusted chain that OpenSSL will then rebuild incorrectly.